# Codeigniter relative path file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter (and php in general) and I am following the tutorial to learn it.
Following this link : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

in the controller it checks whether the a file exists using

```
 if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

My question is: this script is running from application/controllers/pages.php so isn't the path given to `file_exists` relative to the current script ? that is it should point to application/controllers/application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'.

However this is not the case and the path in fact checks files relative to the path root !
So is this php matter or codeigniter ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All paths are relative to the *entry* script (likely `index.php` or whatever Codeigniter uses).

To get paths relative to the current script use the `__FILE__` constant.

```
file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . "/path/to/file.php");
```

Comment: And usually, `index.php` is in the same folder as the `application`, that's why `file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')` works. Since it can be tricky, I usually prefer to give it an absolute path using `file_exists(__DIR__ . 'path/relative/to/current/php/file'` as hakre suggested

Comment: file_exists return true if given path be a directory path . it is better to use is_file() function.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Is this the case with PHP only or with some other languages as well ? as I don't remember that I met this case in any of java,python or c++.

Comment: I don't know about python but Java and C++ are compiled languages so it's moot.